# How to call API with PUCHAR?

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to use an API under Delphi. Here's the API documentation:

```
OKERR ENTRY SCardCLMifareStdAuthent 
    (IN SCARDHANDLE ulHandleCard,IN ULONG ulMifareBlockNr,
    IN UCHAR ucMifareAuthMode,IN UCHAR ucMifareAccessType,IN UCHAR ucMifareKeyNr,
    IN PUCHAR pucMifareKey,IN ULONG ulMifareKeyLen);
```

Whereas `pucMifareKey:`

> A pointer to the six byte Mifare key.

The code I've been trying so far:

```
function Auth():Integer;
type
  TSCardCLMifareStdAuthent = function(SCARDHANDLE: cardinal; ulMifareBlockNr: ULONG;
   ucMifareAuthMode, ucMifareAccessType, ucMifareKeyNr: byte; pucMifareKey: puchar;
   ulMifareKeyLen: cardinal):LONG;
var
  SCardCLMifareStdAuthent: TSCardCLMifareStdAuthent;
  hDLL: Integer;
  CardHandle: cardinal;
  i: integer;
  Key: array of UCHAR;
begin
  Result:=1;
  //CardHandle is defined here
  SetLength(Key, 6);
  for i := low(key) to high(key) do
    Key[i] := $FF;
  hDLL := LoadLibrary('scardsyn.dll');
  @SCardCLMifareStdAuthent := GetProcAddress(hDLL, 'SCardCLMifareStdAuthent');
  if @SCardCLMifareStdAuthent <> nil then
    Result:=SCardCLMifareStdAuthent(CardHandle, $00, 96, 0, 0, ^Key, 6);
  FreeLibrary(hDLL);
end;
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Incompatible types: 'Byte' and 'Char' at the line of
> `Result:=SCardCL.... ` due ^Key pointer.

Any ideas?

Comment: You do not create a pointer in code with the "^" character. That's for DE-referencing something that's already a pointer, and then it appears on the RIGHT of an identifier. When it appears on the left, it needs to precede a TYPE name, and that needs to appear in a type or variable DECLARATION, how within an executable statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the DLL in question, but for a Delphi pre 2009 I would do the following:

```
function Auth: integer;
type
  TSCardCLMifareStdAuthent = function(SCARDHANDLE: cardinal;
    ulMifareBlockNr: ULONG; ucMifareAuthMode, ucMifareAccessType,
    ucMifareKeyNr: byte; pucMifareKey: PAnsiChar;
    ulMifareKeyLen: Cardinal): longint;
var
  SCardCLMifareStdAuthent: TSCardCLMifareStdAuthent;
  hDLL: Integer;
  CardHandle: Cardinal;
  Key: string;
begin
  Result := 1;
  //CardHandle is defined here...
  Key := StringOfChar(Chr($FF), 6);
  hDLL := LoadLibrary('scardsyn.dll');
  if hDLL <> 0 then begin
    @SCardCLMifareStdAuthent := GetProcAddress(hDLL, 'SCardCLMifareStdAuthent');
    if @SCardCLMifareStdAuthent <> nil then begin
      Result := SCardCLMifareStdAuthent(CardHandle, $00, 96, 0, 0,
        PChar(Key), Length(Key));
    end;
    FreeLibrary(hDLL);
  end;
end;
```

The access violation you get probably comes from the C string not being 0-terminated. Using a string and casting it to PChar will make things easier.

Comment: Thank you. The new function seems to work better, although now it gives `application defined exception` - which I think caused from DLL due CardHandle. I'll test and post results later on.

Comment: I'd say it is still missing the calling convention - maybe appending "stdcall;" to the function declaration does help? It is the most probable, although "cdecl;" is also possible; you should check the API documentation for details.

Comment: The API documentation should also tell you whether the key is more like a sequence of chars or a sequence of 8 bit integer numbers - I assumed the former, but if the latter is true using PChar isn't really correct, and you should instead declare a custom type for it instead and make pucMifareKey a pointer to that type.

Answer (score 2):

```
type
  TSCardCLMifareStdAuthent = function(SCARDHANDLE: cardinal; ulMifareBlockNr: ULONG;
    ucMifareAuthMode, ucMifareAccessType, ucMifareKeyNr: byte; pucMifareKey: puchar;
    ulMifareKeyLen: cardinal):LONG;
```

I think you should replace 'byte' with 'UCHAR':

```
ucMifareAuthMode, ucMifareAccessType, ucMifareKeyNr: byte;
```

It is a bad practice to treat 'byte' as a 'char'.

Comment: Thanks for advice, that part is fixed now. But I'm still getting error on pointer variable.

Comment: As long as this is pre Delphi 2009 there is no difference between using char or byte.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't happen to be in Delphi 2009?  If so, "char" is defined as 2 bytes.  Try "AnsiChar" instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Introduce new type for array of UCHAR.
2. Introduce new local variable of pointer type.
3. Set this variable to be pointer to your Key array
4. Use this pointer in function call

   ```
   type 
     TArrayOfUchar = array of UCHAR;

   var 
     ...
     Key  : TArrayOfUchar;
     PKey : ^TArrayOfUchar; 
   begin
     ...
     PKey = @Key;
     if @SCardCLMifareStdAuthent <> nil then
       Result:=SCardCLMifareStdAuthent(CardHandle, $00, 96, 0, 0, PKey, 6);
   ```

Comment: It gives `incompatible types: char and pointer` error at `Pkey:=^Key;` line.

Comment: Sorry. You are both right. Code was not tested and had some stupid mistakes. I think(hope) that edited version is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You stated that the key is a 6 byte (uchar) array. You are declaring a dynamic array to pass along, why not just declare an array?

```
var
  {...}
  MyKey: array[0..5] of UCHAR;
begin
  {...}
  Result:=SCardCLMifareStdAuthent(CardHandle, $00, 96, 0, 0, @MyKey, 6);
```